# How to put the code of upload_image to insertion function with PDO?

Tags: php, pdo

I have here the script for insertion of records in database.i have have here two script one is for insertion of records only and the other is also an insertion function the difference is that the second script is inserting image.now what i want to happen here is that to store the first script and the second script in just one table and should be look like this user_id,username,password,province,FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE,FILE_TYPE.but i don't know how to do that..can someone please help me with it?

**here is the script for the insertion of records**

```
public function create($username,$password,$province)
{
try
{
  $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO login(username,password,province) VALUES(:username, :password, :province)");
  $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
  $stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
  $stmt->bindparam(":province",$province);
  $stmt->execute();
  return true;
  }
  catch(PDOException $e)
  {
  echo $e->getMessage();  
  return false;
  } 
  }
```

**and here is for upload_image**

```
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$query = "INSERT into tish_images(`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`)
         VALUES(:FILE_NAME,:FILE_SIZE,:FILE_TYPE)";
$stmt  = $DB_con->prepare($query);
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error ){
    if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $errors[] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
        continue;
    }
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        continue;
    }
    try{       
        $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_NAME', $file_name , PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_SIZE', $file_size, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_TYPE', $file_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();

        $desired_dir="image_uploads";

        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);// Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_file($desired_dir.'/'.$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name);
        }else{    //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_file=$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name.time();
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$new_file) ;               
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $errors[] = $file_name . 'not saved in db.';
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }   
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
}
```

**here is the index.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbconfig.php';
if(isset($_POST['btn-save']))
{
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$province = $_POST['province'];


if($crud->create($username,$password,$province))
 {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Saved!');</script>";
 }
 else
 {
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Insertion Failed!');</script>";
 }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would not put it together into one large script, but put each in a seperate function and call them from the same function. It would be a more Object Oriented way to do.

Like this:

```
public function createUser($username, $password, $provence)
{
    createDatabaseUser($username, $password, $provence);
    uploadImages();
}

public function createDatabaseUser($username,$password,$province)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->db->prepare("INSERT INTO login(username,password,province) VALUES(:username, :password, :province)");
        $stmt->bindparam(":username",$username);
        $stmt->bindparam(":password",$password);
        $stmt->bindparam(":province",$province);
        $stmt->execute();
        return true;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();  
        return false;
    } 
  }

public function uploadImages()
{
    if(isset($_FILES['files'])){
$query = "INSERT into tish_images(`FILE_NAME`,`FILE_SIZE`,`FILE_TYPE`)
         VALUES(:FILE_NAME,:FILE_SIZE,:FILE_TYPE)";
$stmt  = $DB_con->prepare($query);
$errors= array();
foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $error ){
    if ($error != UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $errors[] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key] . ' was not uploaded.';
        continue;
    }
    $file_name = $key.$_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
    $file_size = $_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
    $file_tmp  = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
    $file_type = $_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
    if($file_size > 2097152){
        $errors[] = 'File size must be less than 2 MB';
        continue;
    }
    try{       
        $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_NAME', $file_name , PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_SIZE', $file_size, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->bindParam( ':FILE_TYPE', $file_type, PDO::PARAM_STR );
        $stmt->execute();

        $desired_dir="image_uploads";

        if(is_dir($desired_dir)==false){
            mkdir($desired_dir, 0700);// Create directory if it does not exist
        }
        if(is_file($desired_dir.'/'.$file_name)==false){
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name);
        }else{    //rename the file if another one exist
            $new_file=$desired_dir.'/'.$file_name.time();
            move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$new_file) ;               
        }
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        $errors[] = $file_name . 'not saved in db.';
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }   
}
if(empty($error)){
    echo "Success";
}
}
}
```

Comment: maybe i can do that but i make a database table with the fields of those two function..like user_id,username,password,province,FILE_NAME,FILE_SIZE,FILET_TYPE all all field are just in single table.